# Is it permissible to do freelancing or learn a new skill while on the job for some company?

Tags: halal-haram, work

During my day job, I have a lot of free time as there are just 1-2 hours of work during the whole day.
I was thinking of doing freelancing during this free time so I can make some extra money or learn a new skill that will help me in keeping myself market relevant.

So, am I allowed to do this? If not then what should I do during this free time that'll help me out in passing the time and is allowed?

Comment: Where is the relevance to Islam here? The main problem belongs to a site like the workspace https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ as the issue here might be a legal issue based on your work contract.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is more likely a fit for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think he is asking whether this is considered stealing from the employer (time, resources) which is a Islam-specific question.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I am here to get some answers. Try to understand my point of view and if you can't then I think you should keep quiet as there are a lot of other people who can help me out in this regard.

Thanks.

P.S It is relevant to Islam because my employer doesn't have any rule regarding this and I can't ask them either. So, it all comes down to this whether I am stealing or not doing the right thing by utilizing my employer's time and resources for my own good. 
Everything related to daily life is related to islam as there are rules for eveything in Islam and I just have to find it.

Comment: I'm here to help you improve and elaborate a good question as that is the aim of this site instead of asking unclear questions! So add any helpful information to your post! Note that your comment still shows no specific connection to Islam and could appear as is on many sites in the network! And as long as it is not fixed you'll become opinion based answers!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the policy of your company, and AFAIK, no company will allow you to do the work for some other bushiness or company as you are being paid to work for the current company.

But for learning new skill that's not a problem as every company wants his employee's to be get updated with latest technologies & skills.

Comment: Please provide evidences to support your claims!